# Meteor collection returns no results except in template

Tags: meteor

I'm new to the Meteor framework, and am having problems accessing data from my collection, outside of a template.
I have a small mongo collection and can retrieve and present its data without problems by using a template.  However, when I try to get a cursor or array to use more directly, I get no results returned.

In my script, using find

`var dataFind = Fakedata.find();
console.log(dataFind);
console.log(dataFind.count());`

gives a cursor object, but a count of zero.

`var dataFetch = Fakedata.find().fetch();
console.log(dataFetch);
console.log(dataFetch.length);`

gives an empty array, length of zero.

Using the same `find()` or `fetch()` from the JS console gives populated objects as I would expect the code above to do. Within a meteor template, everything seems to work fine as well, so the pub/sub seems to be correct.

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your subscriptions aren't `ready` at the time you try to access your collection data, this is a common gotcha.

When you access your collection data via templates, it is most likely via the use of template helpers which happen to be reactive, so they will rerun when your collections are `ready` thus displaying the correct data.

When accessing your collections in a non-reactive script though, they will appear empty if the subscription is not yet `ready`.

You can try using this pattern in your script to execute code only when the subscription is ready :

```
Meteor.subscribe("mySubscription",function(){
  // we are inside the ready callback here so collection date is available
  console.log(Fakedata.find().fetch());
});
```

If you are looking for a more robust approach, try looking at `iron:router` `waitOn` mechanism.

Comment: That seems to be the problem.  I'll look into iron:router to see how that works as well.  Thanks.